# Add custom emojis to my messaging app

Tags: java, android, android-studio, whatsapp, emoji

I would like to switch an emoji in my messenger app. This means if you enter a certain emoji into the text input there is not the android emoji shown, but my Emoji should appear. This should work like WhatsApp with the iOS emojis. There also do not appear the android emoji but special emojis (iOS emojis).

Is there a possibility to implement this? It should work in any case as you see at Whatsapp. But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of work, but...

write your program, so it reads the user input char by char, or token by token. Then when the user enters a sequence of characters representing an emoji, ex :) (which is the same input you would get if they hit the smile face on the keyboard, maybe :-) to) you then don't write the chars to wherever you're writing you instead insert an image view, with the bitmap of the emoji you want to place. If you just write the same chars the default android emoji will appear, or just the chars depending on how you are doing your writing.

Comment: Thank You! That is exactly what i want to do. But I cannot find any (working) example in the Internet how to add an image between some text. I also have a problem with adjusting the size of the image. Do you have an idea?

Comment: @Daniel S. Use picasso to load the image into the image view, and set the size using picasso. Then have the imageview wrap content, so it fits whatever size you pick (I'd make the size a number based on a ratio to the screen size ex 1/8 width and 1/16 height). Then set the position of the imageview using setX, and setY. To figure out the coords you'll have to be recoding the coords of the text as it is written.